# Android Studio 2.2 doesn't show any project with java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-studio, nullpointerexception

I am facing new issue in android studio. I can't see any of my project .Just i can cee a blank screen.

I got the error like this.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.confirmExitIfNeeded(ApplicationImpl.java:877)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.access$900(ApplicationImpl.java:92)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$16.run(ApplicationImpl.java:827)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.exit(ApplicationImpl.java:840)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.exit(ApplicationImpl.java:789)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.exit(ApplicationImpl.java:784)
at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.IdeFrameImpl$5$1.run(IdeFrameImpl.java:275)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.runNextEvent(LaterInvocator.java:345)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.run(LaterInvocator.java:329)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:857)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:658)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:386)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Now i am unable to open all of my projects & facing trouble to finish my task. 
Any Help?

Comment: Did you try to reinstall AS?

Comment: Looks like you have a corrupt IDE system folder (or also the config folder). Can you try to delete system folder and restart Android Studio?

Comment: not installed..

Comment: @MartinRevert where's the location of this folder? please guide me

Comment: It depends on your OS. If it is Windows it is on your "Users" folder or "Documents and Settings". If it is Linux, is on your home user directory. On both cases the folder is called `.AndroidStudioPreview2.2` and inside that could find "config" and "system" folder. When I saw errors like yours in the past, I always recommended to try a new install erasing this 2 folders. Be aware that erasing both folders will imply that you will need to configure Android Studio from zero again, including pointing the IDE to your projects folder if you use a special name and folder for them..

Comment: @MartinRevert before i follow your command , i disable IDE from task manager. after re-opening IDE i get back all project preference. thanks a lot for you time and effort.

Comment: @shihab_returns Glad that can solve the thing. Cheers bro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i can recover the problem. I am using windows OS. I open the task manager and close Android Studio program. After re-opening the Android Studio, I get back all the preference what i set earlier with all projects link up.

@Martin Revert Solution can be followed. But Remember, all project preference will be erased and may be you have to set SDK path and all necessary things. Else you can follow my solution.